# How to get redirect from non-www to www on a Meteor app

Tags: node.js, redirect, heroku, meteor, subdomain

I am trying to redirect all of my non-www traffic to my www domain.  If I type in `example.com` in, it redirects to the proper https://www.example.com.  However, if I type in http://example.com or https://example.com, I get an infinite redirect loop.

I have setup URL forwarding with Namecheap an am hosting on Heroku.

Currently, I have this in my server code, which is creating the redirect loop (without it I just get an error):

```
WebApp.connectHandlers
    .use(function(req, res, next) {
      var uri = new URI(req.originalUrl);
      if (uri.subdomain() != 'www') {
        uri.normalizeProtocol();
        res.writeHead(301, {
          'Location': 'https://www.example.com' + uri.resource()
        });
        res.end();
      } else {
        next();
      }
    });
```

I am using URI.js to parse the url.  Any ideas on how I can change this?

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend to disable the URL forwarding in Namecheap and handle this directly in your app stack.

After that there are few options:

1. If you are using a proxy like nginx to serve it then this could help:
   [How To Redirect www to Non-www with Nginx on CentOS 7](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-redirect-www-to-non-www-with-nginx-on-centos-7)
2. If you are serving directly, then maybe at router level - in [Iron Router](http://iron-meteor.github.io/iron-router/)

   ```
    Router.route("addWWW", {
         where: "server",
         path: "*",
         action: function() {
           var fullUrl, host;        
           host = this.request.headers.host;

           if (host.indexOf("www") !== 0) {
             fullUrl = "http://wwww." + host + this.request.url;
             this.response.writeHead(HTTP_REDIRECT_PERMANENT, {
               Location: fullUrl
             });
             return this.response.end();
           }
         }
       });
   ```